# How to combine 3D figure with LogLogPlot to produce 2D figure

Tags: plotting, dataset, logarithmic-scale

I have (x,y,z) set of data and I want to combine 3D figure with LogLogPlot and to produce 2D figure

```
data = {{5.999996331469935`, 0.5500005474260047`, 2.549565417296867`*^-6}, {5.999991969344593`, 0.5500011983651819`, 2.848318110201032`*^-6}, {5.999986835624129`, 0.5500019644590124`, 3.201464984098217`*^-6}, {5.999980785205914`, 0.5500028673638228`,  3.617646710577001`*^-6}, {5.999973648902611`, 0.5500039323308369`, 4.108652222464897`*^-6}, {5.999965224629254`, 0.5500051895216201`, 4.688439179456477`*^-6}, {5.999955271226099`, 0.5500066749302207`, 5.373677492244699`*^-6}, {5.999943500721313`, 0.550008431538252`,  6.184276903603515`*^-6}, {5.999929569067917`, 0.5500105106978175`,  7.144029569135982`*^-6}, {5.999913065019908`, 0.550012973792352`, 8.281381033889173`*^-6}};

p1 = ListPointPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotLegends -> Automatic]

A = 1 - 1.47/x^0.999;
p2 = LogLogPlot[A, {x, .1, 50}]
```

Is there way to do this? [image: I need the final result like this figure]

Comment: Since your goal is to get a true 2D plot in the end, you'll have to project the points onto a plane somehow - why not simply do that before plotting them? Then `ListPointPlot` and `Show` are all you need

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks for your comment, but what about the colored bar which give the information about "Z"?

Comment: Good point - you could emulate `ListPlot` using `Graphics` with something like `Graphics@With[{max=Max@data[[All,3]]},{ColorData["Rainbow"][#3/max],Point[{#,#2}]}&@@@data}]`. And you can manually build the legend using `BarLegend` and `Legended`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way than what I've suggested in the comments is the following:

```
p1 = ListPointPlot3D[
  data,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large],
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", "Linear"}
];

A = 1 - 1.47/x^0.999;
p2 = LogLogPlot[A, {x, .1, 50}];

Show[p2, p1 /. g_Graphics3D :> Graphics[First@g /. Point@{x_, y_, z_} :> Point@{x, y}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Note the `ScalingFunctions` option for `p1`)

The idea is to replace the `Graphics3D` expression with a `Graphics` one, where we project all the points onto the plane. But I guess you need to adjust this projection a bit, as the points overlap currently.

Comment: I've an error with ScalingFunctions, it was in red.

Comment: @Shaaban what version of Mathematica do you have?

Comment: I solved this problem using Show[p2, p1 /. g_Graphics3D :> Graphics[First@g /. Point@{x_, y_, z_} :> Point@{Log10[x], Log10[y]}]]
 and delete ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", "Linear"} 
Many thanks